# Kafka inter broker SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup inter-broker SSL (not client) authentication and keep seeing the following errors:

```
[2019-05-17 06:33:47,151] INFO [Controller id=1004, targetBrokerId=1004] Failed authentication with /$IP (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-17 06:33:47,151] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1004] Failed authentication with /$IP (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-17 06:33:47,151] ERROR [Controller id=1004, targetBrokerId=1004] Connection to node 1004 (/$IP:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

My server.properties is:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://$IP:9092,SSL://$IP:9093
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.password=$PASS
ssl.keystore.password=$PASS
ssl.key.password=$PASS
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=""
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
``

When I run `openssl s_client -debug -connect $IP:9093 -tls1` I get back a list of certificates and `Secure Renegotiation IS supported` 

Despite adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` there's not anything in the logs which points to the problem. 

Kafka version 2.2

Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly set the value of `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=""` instead of `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm"`, this fixed it.

This value was changed in 2.2 to default to `https` so setting it to nothing worked.